# Vue multi conditions in table row

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm new to working with Vue and I'm a bit stuck. I have figured out binding and  usage of `v-if` conditionals in terms of showing one thing if condition is true or false, but I'm lost on how to take a conditional for showing multiple possiblities as an if/else/else basically. I have this:

```
<td v-if="dateEvent.id=== '2' && dateEvent.name === 'Title'"><button" type="button" class=" taskButton btn-default"><a style="color:white;">Accept</a></button></td>
```

Which works by saying that if the id and name match then show the row with the button. What I want to do is use `dateEvent.status` and say `if status = 'O' show this button, else if status = 'P' show "In Progress" else if status = 'C' show "Completed"`

How can I make this one row show at all times but only show a button or different text based on the status in the object?

Comment: Is this not just `v-else` and `v-else-if`? https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-if

Comment: I think I misunderstood the usage of that. SO I could have 4 stacked <Td> elements with the if/else but I'd still only be showing one based on the condition out of the 4 possibilities

Comment: if you have several criteria to decide on a value, that value is most of the times well suited for a computed property. In this way, the template will be simplified significantly and you will have a much finer-grained control over the conditionals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use computed

I think it should work

`<td>{{status}}</td>`

```
computed: {
status(){
  if(dateEvent.status === 'O'){
    return `<button" type="button" class=" taskButton btn-default"><a style="color:white;">Accept</a></button>`
  }else{
    if(dateEvent.status === 'P'){
      return 'In Progress'
    }else{
      return 'Completed'
    }
  }
}
```

}